# Should one read ECMA-334 C# Spec to become an expert in C#

Tags: c#

I came to here from a friend of mine that, to master the C# language, one must go through the [ECMA C# spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf). Is this true?

Comment: That strongly depends on what it means to "master" a language...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ECMA spec is sadly out of date. Reading the [*annotated MS spec*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321741765) is useful, but not essential. Really, just use C#... lots. And read books like [C# in Depth](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182471).

Comment: Thank you very much for the "Annotated MS Spec" link.

Answer (score 2):

I voted to close this question as subjective and argumentative. Nevertheless, I want to express my opinion on this:
In my opinion, it is only necessary to have an understanding *that* deep, if you want to write compilers or parsers for C#. Otherwise, it is more important to have a good understanding of the .NET framework and what you can do with it.

Comment: I went through some pages and found that it was discussing lexical stuff. So what I could understand from your response is its for the language developers or tools developers. Thanks for that.

Comment: I've never written a compiler or parser for C#, but I still find the C# spec invaluable. Want to understand why you're getting a mysterious compilation error? Consult the spec. Want to know whether a particular bit of behaviour is guaranteed? Consult the spec.